# Does Neo4j v2.2.3 support indexes be added to property arrays for use the IN where clause?

Tags: neo4j

I know earlier of version of Neo4j could not use indexes except for exact matching to the entire array.

For example, in 1.9 the following could benefit from an index on `:thing(someproperty)`:

```
 MATCH (n:thing) WHERE ['big','fat'] = n.someproperty return n LIMIT 10
```

However, this would not:

```
MATCH (n:thing) WHERE 'big' in n.someproperty return n LIMIT 10
```

Has later versions allowed indexing that works will elements of a property array?

Comment: Not yet, it is planned for some future version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is not supported in v2.2.3 according to the comment provided by someone who works for Neo4J.